# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__' in syft import

Tags: python, tensorflow, attributeerror

I was trying to import syft but the following error popped

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-281ee5c8ca5f>", line 1, in <module>
    import syft as sy

  File "C:\Users\neeraj bansal\Downloads\syft-0.2.9\syft-0.2.9\syft\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from syft import dependency_check

  File "C:\Users\neeraj bansal\Downloads\syft-0.2.9\syft-0.2.9\syft\dependency_check.py", line 10, in <module>
    if LooseVersion(tensorflow.__version__) < LooseVersion("2.0.0"):    
**AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__'**
```

I have latest tensorflow version installed

Comment: do you have a script called tensorflow.py?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Yes, this is the folder location  C:\Users\neeraj bansal\Anaconda3\pkgs\sympy-1.4-py37_0\Lib\site-packages\sympy\printing.

Comment: I mean a tensorflow.py in the same folder as your own scripts, not inside installed packages

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy that worked. thanks!!